Bazel seems to ignore CPU requirement tag
I have many large integration tests with Bazel defined with sh_test(). Relevant attributes look like this:
sh_test(
    name = "example_integration_test",
    tags = ["cpu:6"],
    size = "large",
    flaky = True,
)

I pass the follow resource options to Bazel:
--jobs=HOST_CPUS
--local_resources=cpu=HOST_CPUS
--local_resources=memory=HOST_RAM

On a CI machine with 8 CPUs I'm finding Bazel most of the time running 4 actions at once. Here's an example Bazel output where test names have been replaced with //:example_n_integration_test:
(21:21:56) [2,681 / 2,705] 16 / 40 tests; 8 actions, 4 running; last test: //:example_1_integration_test
    Testing //:example_2_integration_test; 519s linux-sandbox, remote-cache
    Testing //:example_3_integration_test; 357s linux-sandbox, remote-cache
    Testing //:example_4_integration_test; 82s linux-sandbox, remote-cache
    Testing //:example_5_integration_test; 0s linux-sandbox, remote-cache
    [Sched] Testing //:example_6_integration_test; 228s
    [Sched] Testing //:example_7_integration_test; 205s
    [Sched] Testing //:example_8_integration_test; 183s
    [Sched] Testing //:example_9_integration_test; 159s

I've tried increasing the CPU tag to cpu:40 but I still get multiple tests running in parallel. Why is Bazel ignoring my CPU requirement tag? I'd expect given a CPU requirement of 6 then only one of these tests could run at once on an 8 core machine. What are these [Sched] lines in the output? (I'm guessing they're not running actions.) I'm running Bazel 7.2.0.

Note that only --jobs controls how many actions (tests in this case) run in parallel. cpu in tags controls how many CPUs the actions get

I updated my answer with a reference to the Bazel slack and the findings from there. Hopefully that helps!

Updated Answer
Here, we can see that resources:memory:N and resources:cpu:N, where N is an integer. I think that has the best chance of working.
There's a good discussion of this on the Bazel slack, here.
Original Answer
Looking at the bazel docs, there are other tags which can affect test execution:

https://bazel.build/reference/be/common-definitions#common.tags
https://bazel.build/reference/test-encyclopedia#tag-conventions

Another solution might be tagging the tests as exclusive, which prevents other actions being run at the same time; that doesn't work if you have arbitrary CPU considerations though.
This question is related as well.
One final idea: set a timeout instead of the test size. You're asking for specific resources, so the large part which selects the resources can only possibly conflict with your cpus request.
